# MVC 4 Sitemap Localization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, localization, mvcsitemapprovider

Firstly I started working on having multiple cultures in my MVC 4 application. I Added the usual data in global.asax to change the culture of the current thread and added a folder "Resources" which will have the resources as needed "Example.resx, Example.it.resx" etc. This all works and changes the text of my application well.

Now in my _Lavout.cshtml I am building a menu using the MVC sitemap

Inside the Mvc.sitemap file I have as follows:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <mvcSiteMap xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-4.0"             xsi:schemaLocation="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-4.0 MvcSiteMapSchema.xsd" >

    <mvcSiteMapNode resourceKey="DashboardText" title="Dashboard" controller="Home" action="Index" imageUrl="glyphicon glyphicon-home" description="dashboard">

    </mvcSiteMapNode>
    </mvcSiteMap>
```

In the resources file I have A key for "DashboardText" and the value is garbled text so see it working. This is not working and the text remains what is written in the title. 
I have tried adding `<add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_EnableLocalization" value="true"/>` in the `<appSettings>` inside the web.config but nothing happened .

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

So I figured this out, here is what I did:

1. Did not add anything in the web.config
2. Created a new folder > App_GlobalResources and added a new resource file dedicated only for the menu items.
3. Finally in the sitemap I removed the ResourceKey and I changed the title to `title="$resources:<ResXFileName>,<keyName>"`.

Basically I separated the translations for page content and translations for menu content.